# Storing pictures in a database on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

everyone. I am trying to create a database in which I can store pictures on phpMyAdmin. The pictures should be in a separate field of the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd ideally want to store the location of the file in the database vs. the actual image in the database so the database does not grow in size substantially.

You can use something along the lines of:

```
table: img_location
columns: id|title|url
```

Comment: Thanks Duniyadnd, I appreciate this. This makes more sense. I'll try it.